# Proofs for certain ways of decomposing permutations as products of transpositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know $(1 2 3 4 5) = (15)(14)(13)(12)$.

But I just discovered $(12345) = (12)(23)(34)(45)$ and $(12345) = (54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)$.

Also, $(15) = (21)(32)(43)(54)(43)(32)(21)$.

Excepting the first one that I know already, where do these methods of permutation decompositions come from? I couldn't find their proofs.

Comment: You gave examples of decompositions, not a method of decomposition.

Comment: Ok. Where can I find their proofs?

Comment: Are you saying you found these decompositions but you don't know how to check whether they in fact yield $(12345)$ when you compose them?

Comment: I know $(a_1 a_2 ... a_r) = (a_1 a_r)(a_1 a_{r−1})\cdots (a_1 a_2)$. It has a proof. But what's the justification for $(a_1 a_2 ... a_r) = (a_1 a_2)(a_2 a_3)\cdots (a_{r - 1} a_r)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compose permutations, you can track what happens to the individual elements. For example, to check $(12345)=(54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)$, apply each transposition, starting on the right:

$$
12345\\
32145\\
23145\\
53142\\
53241\\
23541\\
23451
$$

The result is the same as that of applying $(12345)$.

Comment: Suppose we need to prove the identity $(a_1 a_2 ... a_r) = (a_1 a_2)(a_2 a_3)\cdots (a_{r - 1} a_r)$. Can we compose/turn the right side into the left side and call it a proof?

Comment: @user253061: I don't understand the question. How else would you prove that a product of permutations equals another permutation? You wrote "I know $(a_1 a_2 ... a_r) = (a_1 a_r)(a_1 a_{r−1})\cdots (a_1 a_2)$. It has a proof." Perhaps if you write down that proof I'll get a better idea of what you "call" a proof.

Comment: Note the product on the right-hand side sends $a_1 →a_2, a_2 →a_3,..., a_r →a_1$ and fixes everything else, which is exactly what the $r$-cycle $(a_1 a_2 ... a_r)$ on the left-hand side does. So the two sides
are equal. Well. I guess these proofs are equivalent. Ok. I have one last question. How did they derive the right hand side from the left hand side in $(12345) = (54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)$?

Comment: @user253061: I have no idea how they did it -- there are various ways of coming up with sequences of transpositions that yield a given permutation. For instance, you could use a table as in my answer above, starting with $12345$, start out with a couple of arbitrary transpositions and then apply transpositions that move the numbers into the right places to end up with $23451$.